# How to input an array list and output sum in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have this code that reads an array list until the user enters 0 and calculate the sum of the array. My way only read half of the input. Please help me check and find out what is wrong. Thank you!!

Here is the supposed input and output
(sample input)
1 2 3 2 1 0
(sample output from Eclipse - includes both input and output)
This program will store numbers in an ArrayList and compute the sum of numbers.
Enter the numbers one at a time. Enter a 0 to terminate the input.
1 2 3 2 1 0
The items in the ArrayList are [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0]
There are 5 items in the ArrayList
The sum of items in the ArrayList is 9.0

and here is what I am working on

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class SumArrayList {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
    int n=0;
    double sumVal = 0;
    System.out.println("This program will store numbers in an ArrayList and compute the sum of numbers.\r\n" + 
            "Enter the numbers one at a time. Enter a 0 to terminate the input.");
    while(scnr.nextDouble() != 0)
    {
        list.add(scnr.nextDouble());
    }
    System.out.print("The items in the ArrayList are ");
    for(int i=0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.print(list.get(i) + " ");
        sumVal += list.get(i);
        n = i+1;
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("There are " + n + " items in the ArrayList");
    System.out.println("The sum of " + n + " items in the ArrayList is " + sumVal);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You are using `nextDouble` twice therefore it is expecting twice the input

try

```
double value = scnr.nextDouble();
while(value != 0)
{
    list.add(value);
    value = scnr.nextDouble();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the stats (and not the values) you could dispense with your list altogether and just keep the aggregate. Something like:

```
DoubleSummaryStatistics stats = DoubleStream.generate(scnr::nextDouble)
    .takeWhile(d -> d > 0).summaryStatistics();
```

You then have count, sum, average, range available.